# Decoding an obfuscated value - Unable to convert data to string

Tags: ios, swift, utf-8

I am working on importing a file from a legacy C++ codebase. The file itself is technically a JSON but one of the values is obfuscated with an XOR function in the C++ codebase before I receive it and looks something like this.

```
{"version": 15, "data": "C\u0016Q45\u0010 46QY\\\u0011\n\u0019a\u0003\u0019}\u001apg"}
```

The value for "data" is technically a UTF8 string.

I know the algorithm used to decode that data into a usable JSON string. However, I am unable to get swift to parse this into a [String : String] apparently due to formatting issues.

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unable to convert data to string around character 31."
```

So far I have managed to get the specific data in question by isolating the subdata

```
 let encryptedData = data.subdata(in: dataPrefixLength ..< dataLength - 2)
```

Even still, I cannot seem to get swift to parse this into a String when I attempt to do so with UTF8 encoding.

```
String(data: encryptedData, encoding: .utf8)
```

It's also worth noting that the String description seems alright in the debugger when inspecting the data itself.

I'd really appreciate any advice. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From your example it looks as if the *obfuscation* generates binary data and the binary data is put into a string. That's not allowed in JSON. Therefore, it's invalid JSON and any parser with a reasonable amount of validation will reject it.

As an example, take the start of the string:

```
"C\u0016
```

It starts with the character "C". That's valid.

Then an escaped character with a hexadecimal values follows: `0016`. However, U+0016 is not a valid Unicode codepoint. Therefore it's rejected. It's probably supposed to be the binary byte 0x16. But you can't put that into a JSON string.

You have two options:

1. Fix the source of the data, e.g. by using a Base64 encoding before putting binary data into JSON.
2. Write your own JSON parser to handle the invalid JSON.

Comment: \u00016 is a valid unicode code point.  Specifically it's "synchronous idle" and is classified as a control character.  [See here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0016/index.htm)  But in general, treating binary data as UTF-8 is fragile at best.